# Find duplicate letters in an anagram

Tags: java, string

Im writing a program that is very similar to the show Countdown. There is a bunch of letters and you make words from it.

I have the basics done, where the word submitted by the user is checked against the base word, if the chars match, then it is checked against a dictionary which is an online API. The scores are then added to a top 10 leaderboard. I have all of this implemented but I am now facing my final issue and I can't seem to solve.

```
// convert the users guess to a char array
char [] chars = word.toCharArray();

for(char c : chars){
    int charIndex = baseWord.indexOf(c);

    if(charIndex != -1){
        continue;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The letter " + c + " is not in " + baseWord);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I convert the users guess to a char array and then compare each element of the char array to the element of the base word. This works fine until I have duplicate records. For example if I have the base word set to `areallylongword` and the user guess is set to `adder`, this returns true while it should return false.

I understand the concept that the `int charIndex = baseWord.indexOf(c)` will return the same value when char `d` is looked up.

How do I go about avoiding this issue?

Comment: i don't watch the show so i don't understand you very well is the game is the User has a bunch of letters and should make a word out off it ??

Comment: so what is the baseWord

Comment: Yea exactly so the base word is set to `areallylongword` and other words have to be made out of it. One of the words in the program is `adder` which should be false because there is only 1 D in the base word but it is passing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just blank the letters in the `baseWord` when you find a match:

```
// convert the users guess to a char array
char [] chars = word.toCharArray();

for(char c : chars){
    int charIndex = baseWord.indexOf(c);

    if(charIndex != -1){
        char[] baseWordChars = baseWord.toCharArray();
        baseWordChars[charIndex] = '#';  // char wiped
        baseWord = new String(baseWordChars);
        continue;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The letter " + c + " is not in " + baseWord);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I have a test of 6 words to run against the base word and it fails because all of the matched characters are now `#`

Comment: Just make a copy of the base word and perform the matching and wiping within that copy

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the letters from the baseWord once they are matched

Answer (score 1):

Count the Char occurrences into an array or a hash, then decrease the count of the guessed word.

For instance if you assume that baseWords should contains letters ASCI-128, you can create an array with 128 position and use the charcode as the index of your letter.

```
char [] chars = word.toCharArray();
int[] charCount = int[128]; // By default every position is 0
for (c : chars) {
   charCount[c] += 1; // Increments the count of char 
}
```

Then you go through the user's guess word, and decrease from this charCount, to verify if the user guessed right you should never have a negative number on charCount.

```
char[] c = guess.toCharArray();
for (c : chars) {
   charCount[c] -= 1;
   if (charCount[c] < 0) {
     return 0;
   }
}
```